# Binding events in WebView on Android 2.2

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, android-webview

I'm not able to bind tap and swipe events to in my App using a WebView with a simple sample code that works fine in the browser. I'm using JQuery Mobile. Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>jQuery Mobile Events</title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-           1.0a3.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$( function() {
$('body').bind( 'taphold', function( e ) {
alert( 'You tapped and held!' );
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
return false;
} );  
$('body').bind( 'swipe', function( e ) {
alert( 'You swiped!' );
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
return false;
} );  
} );
</script>  
</head>
<body> 
<div data-role="page" id="home">
<div data-role="header">
<h1>jQuery Mobile Events</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content"> 
<p>Try:</p>
<ul>
  <li>Tapping and holding</li>
  <li>Swiping</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my code in Java:

```
WebView webview;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webview.loadUrl("web-page-here");
    webview.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
}
```

Here's the Javascript interface:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class JavaScriptInterface {
Context mContext;
AudioRecord audiorecord;
/** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

/** Show a toast from the web page */
public void showToast(String toast) {
    Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

// OnSwipe() here?
}
```

So I should probably add method here and when swipe is detected it should be called in JQuery with Android.OnSwipe()? Why doesn't the above JQuery Mobile code work for navigating? Shouldn't WebView work like a web browser?

Comment: Just a tip: there is a newer version of jQuery than 1.5 (1.5.1 and 1.5.2)

Answer (score 0):

1. You should show how you implemented JavaScriptInterface
2. There doesn't seem to be any propagation from the JS even you have, to your actual Android JS bridge. In the JS code, you should call something like Android.onSwipe() and implemente onSwipe in JavaScriptInterface.